# How can I find out why Yahoo! classifies my mail as spam?

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

I've a Yahoo! email account and when sending emails from my company to it, they always at first get into Spam. It's not about that I can't find the "No spam" buttons, but whenever someone from our company sends someone at Yahoo an email, until it's properly flagged, they all at first are getting disposed, and missed, into the Spam folder.

Alas I'm not able to figure out what kind of policies are responsible for classifying those emails as spam. We're running out own Microsoft 2003 Exchange based email server, but don't have such problems with others (Hotmail, Gmail, web.de, etc.).

Is there any chance to find out what's troubling Yahoo!?

Comment: I wonder if this might be better asked at http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get any direct information out of Yahoo! as that would potentially give spammers an edge in the never ending war between the spammers and spam filters.

Have you analysed the headers as received by the Yahoo! account? They might contain some information inserted by the spam filter.

Other than that, contact Yahoo! and explain the situation. They might be able to add your domain onto their white list.

Comment: The headers didn't contain anything in addition.